# D3.js force directed graph, Displaying text over the lines joining Source and Target

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I am new to D3.js force directed graph and have followed the example given in http://www.d3noob.org/2013/03/d3js-force-directed-graph-example-basic.html

[image]

The example perfectly fits to my requirement, but i need one small help: I want to display some information over the lines joining the source and the target on each node (ideally in the center of the lines joining the source and the target).

If any one has done this before, please let me know. Also, please let me know if there's any other graph which I can use?

if there's a similar question please move this thread on that question.

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663844/add-text-label-onto-links-in-d3-force-directed-graph)?

Comment: Hi Lars, Thanks or the link, that's what i wanted, but i have a small question here.
Can i read one more value from JsonArray (which i am doing now, which includes source,target and type)
I want to send one more tag named distance something like this
code var links = [
  {source: "Microsoft", target: "Amazon", type: "toSource" ,distance:"10"},
  {source: "Nokia", target: "Qualcomm", type: "toTarget",distance:"20"}
]; code 
and place the distance value on the edge?
Since i am reading it from JSONarray it will be easier for me.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean -- this question explains how to add labels to the links. Is that not what you want?

Comment: Hi Lars,After some playing with the code i was able to display the text as i wanted over the lines.
Please have a look at the modification here http://jsfiddle.net/ashishyete/DEeNB/

Thanks,
Ashish

Comment: If that solved your problem, could you post it as an answer please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made a small update as per the JSON array i had

```
var links = [
    {source: "Apple", target: "Nokia", type: "resolved",distance:"25"},
  {source: "Qualcomm", target: "Nokia", type: "resolved",distance:"30"},
  {source: "Apple", target: "Motorola", type: "suit",distance:"35"},
  {source: "Microsoft", target: "Motorola", type: "suit",distance:"40"},
  {source: "Motorola", target: "Microsoft", type: "suit",distance:"45"}
];
```

I am able to read from the distance tag from the JSON array and place it in the text over the lines,
Now the graph will be complete Dynamic,(i.e) Everything is read from a JSON Array and displayed.
The solution is http://jsfiddle.net/DEeNB/36/