# d3js force layout, add text to link

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Thanks for reading. I'm trying to build a force layout with d3js and would like to add some text on the links, e.g. SVG lines. I tried to do so with the code below. When I use the debugger I see that the text is added to the svg, but somehow it is not correctly displayed on the screen. Any clue what might be wrong?

```
var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(json.links)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "link");

link.append("svg:text")
    .attr("class", "linklabel")
    .style("font-size", "13px")
    .attr("x", "50")
    .attr("y", "-50")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .style("fill","#000")
    .attr("xlink:href",function(d,i) { return "#linkId_" + i;})
    .text(function(d) { 
        return "my text"; //Can be dynamic via d object 
    });

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(json.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .call(force.drag);

node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 30)
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });
```

Comment: You can't append `text` elements to `line` elements. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663844/add-text-label-onto-links-in-d3-force-directed-graph

Comment: I voted to close this as a duplicate since the link @LarsKotthoff provides, really covers it, especially this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25783612/16363).  **But** for what it's worth, here's the [simplest example](http://plnkr.co/edit/UPBLjAtFnT3Sw2zO2wUW?p=preview) I can quickly code up.

Comment: Seconded. Please feel free to edit and reopen if your problem is different.