# Edge Labels Not Shown

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, label, d3-force-directed

I am trying to implement labeled edges on a force directed graph.

The example I use can be found [here](http://bl.ocks.org/jhb/5955887).

The relevant bits of code in the example are given [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fL9pLoww/).

My code is the following:

```html
<style>
.node {
    stroke: #fff;
    stroke-width: 0.5px;
}

.node text {
    pointer-events: none;
    font: 15px helvetica;
}

.link {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #bbb;
    stroke-width: 3.0px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.highlight {
    stroke: #259359;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src= "//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" > </script> 
<script>

    var width = 700,
        height = 550;


    var color = d3.scale.category20();

    var force = d3.layout.force()
        .linkStrength(1)
        .distance(0.01)
        .gravity(0.2)
        .charge(-500)
        .size([width, height]);

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);
    svg.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
        .data(["end"]) // Different link/path types can be defined here
        .enter().append("marker") // This section adds in the arrows
        .attr("id", String)
        .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
        .attr("refX", 16)
        .attr("refY", 0)
        .attr("markerWidth", 3)
        .attr("markerHeight", 3)
        .attr("orient", "auto")
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5")
        .style("stroke", "#bbb");


    d3.json("fg.json", function(error, graph) {
        if (error) throw error;


        var nodes = graph.nodes.slice(),
            links = [],
            bilinks = [];

        graph.links.forEach(function(link) {
            var s = nodes[link.source],
                t = nodes[link.target],
                i = {}; // intermediate node
            nodes.push(i);
            links.push({
                source: s,
                target: i
            }, {
                source: i,
                target: t
            });
            bilinks.push([s, i, t]);
        });

        force
            .nodes(nodes)
            .links(links)
            .size([width, height])
            .start();

        var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
            .data(bilinks)
            .enter().append("path")
            .attr("class", "link")
            .style("marker-end", "url(#end)")
            .on("mouseover", function() {
                d3.select(d3.event.target).classed("highlight", true);
            })
            .on("mouseout", function() {
                d3.select(d3.event.target).classed("highlight", false);
            });

        var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
            .data(graph.nodes)
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .call(force.drag)

        node.append("circle")
            .attr("r", 8)
            .style("fill", function(d) {
                return color(d.group);
            })
        node.append("text")
            .attr("dx", 15)
            .attr("dy", ".40em")
            .text(function(d) {
                return d.name
            })
            .style("stroke", "gray");


        //

        var padding = 30, // separation between circles
            radius = 1;

        function collide(alpha) {
            var quadtree = d3.geom.quadtree(graph.nodes);
            return function(d) {
                var rb = 2 * radius + padding,
                    nx1 = d.x - rb,
                    nx2 = d.x + rb,
                    ny1 = d.y - rb,
                    ny2 = d.y + rb;
                quadtree.visit(function(quad, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
                    if (quad.point && (quad.point !== d)) {
                        var x = d.x - quad.point.x,
                            y = d.y - quad.point.y,
                            l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
                        if (l < rb) {
                            l = (l - rb) / l * alpha;
                            d.x -= x *= l;
                            d.y -= y *= l;
                            quad.point.x += x;
                            quad.point.y += y;
                        }
                    }
                    return x1 > nx2 || x2 < nx1 || y1 > ny2 || y2 < ny1;
                });
            };
        }

    var edgepaths = svg.selectAll(".edgepath")
        .data(graph.links)
        .enter()
        .append('path')
        .attr({'d': function(d) {return 'M '+d.source.x+' '+d.source.y+' L '+ d.target.x +' '+d.target.y},
               'class':'edgepath',
               'fill-opacity':0,
               'stroke-opacity':0,
               'fill':'blue',
               'stroke':'red',
               'id':function(d,i) {return 'edgepath'+i}})
        .style("pointer-events", "none");

    var edgelabels = svg.selectAll(".edgelabel")
        .data(graph.links)
        .enter()
        .append('text')
        .style("pointer-events", "none")
        .attr({'class':'edgelabel',
               'id':function(d,i){return 'edgelabel'+i},
               'dx':80,
               'dy':0,
               'font-size':10,
               'fill':'#aaa'});

    edgelabels.append('textPath')
        .attr('xlink:href',function(d,i) {return '#edgepath'+i})
        .style("pointer-events", "none")
        .text(function(d,i){return 'label '+i});

        force.on("tick", function() {
            link.attr("d", function(d) {
                return "M" + d[0].x + "," + d[0].y + "S" + d[1].x + "," + d[1].y + " " + d[2].x + "," + d[2].y;
            });
            node.attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
            });

            edgepaths.attr('d', function(d) { var path='M '+d.source.x+' '+d.source.y+' L '+ d.target.x +' '+d.target.y;
                                               return path});       

            edgelabels.attr('transform',function(d,i){
                if (d.target.x<d.source.x){
                    bbox = this.getBBox();
                    rx = bbox.x+bbox.width/2;
                    ry = bbox.y+bbox.height/2;
                    return 'rotate(180 '+rx+' '+ry+')';
                    }
                else {
                    return 'rotate(0)';
                    }
            });
           node.each(collide(0.5));
        });


    });

</script>
```

The data is given below:

```
    {
      "nodes":[
        {"name":"alkene","group":1},
        {"name":"alkane","group":1},
        {"name":"halogenoalkane","group":2},
        {"name":"dihalogenoalkane","group":2},
        {"name":"amine","group":3},
        {"name":"alcohol","group":4},
        {"name":"ketone","group":5},
        {"name":"aldehyde","group":6},
        {"name":"hydroxynitrile","group":7},
        {"name":"ester","group":8},
        {"name":"carboxylic acid","group":9},
        {"name":"acyl chloride","group":9},
        {"name":"amide","group":10},
        {"name":"nitrile","group":11}
      ],
      "links":[
        {"source":0,"target":2,"value":2},
        {"source":0,"target":1,"value":1},
        {"source":2,"target":0,"value":8},
        {"source":0,"target":3,"value":10},
        {"source":2,"target":4,"value":10},
        {"source":5,"target":2,"value":1},
        {"source":2,"target":5,"value":1},
        {"source":6,"target":5,"value":1},
        {"source":5,"target":6,"value":1},
        {"source":7,"target":5,"value":1},
        {"source":5,"target":7,"value":1},
        {"source":7,"target":8,"value":2},
        {"source":7,"target":10,"value":1},
        {"source":10,"target":7,"value":1},
        {"source":5,"target":9,"value":3},
        {"source":10,"target":9,"value":3},
        {"source":13,"target":10,"value":5},
        {"source":10,"target":11,"value":1},
        {"source":11,"target":10,"value":1},
        {"source":11,"target":12,"value":1}
      ]
    }
```

Unfortunately, the labels on the graph are not visible.

The final objective is to show the corresponding value "value" on each edge.

Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you for your time.

UPDATE

The labels were sucessfully added to the edges by subbing

```
"M" + d[0].x + "," + d[0].y + "S" + d[1].x + "," + d[1].y + " " + d[2].x + "," + d[2].y
```

for

```
'M '+d.source.x+' '+d.source.y+' L '+ d.target.x +' '+d.target.y
```

However, the question remains: how can the "value" datum be added instead of the labels "label i"? Moreover, how can their appearance on mouseover be implemented?

UPDATE II

The "value" datum was made to be shown by defining .data(graph.links) for textPath of edgelabels and then returning a d.value. Could you please tell me how the mouseover can be implemented? It would be nice if the "value" datum of each edge would be seen only on hover. Thank you!

Comment: You're code doesnt even run for a start. Anyway, with that being said, you cant append a textpath to text you have to append it to a g element for example

Comment: Dear thatOneGuy, thank you for your help. The newest version of my post was shortened without testing. I have reversed to the initial version, which includes all the code I have. I am sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @thatOneGuy , could you please tell me how the text can be appended to a g element of the edge?

Comment: @thatOneGuy , there is some information in the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663844/add-text-label-onto-links-in-d3-force-directed-graph . However, I cannot implement any answer, and the answer by Sanjeev in particular.

Comment: Why are you trying to append two paths ? line and edge ?

Comment: @thatOneGuy, I am not sure what I should do. Adding two paths did the job, however, and the labels are shown. However, I cannot implement their appearance on mouseover now and would be really grateful for your help.

Comment: it hasnt done the job as the second (edge not link) is not shown and produces errors. Also the data you're using for the link doesn't look right. Why has it got 3 nodes in each set of data ? For bilinks i mean

Comment: @thatOneGuy, here is the jfiddle with the similar effect I am trying to achieve: https://jsfiddle.net/ud1mpko5/ . It would be nice to have the labels appear over the edges, but if the labels can be shown as in the jfiddle, it would be great too.

Comment: is this on the nodes or the links ? Your links current have a dataset that is an array containing 3 objects. What is it you want to happen ?

Comment: @thatOneGuy, the edge not link should not be shown, and I have thought it acts just as a guide for the labels, which *are* shown. The graph is directed, and shows several directed edges from nodes, and sometimes there are two edges for the same two nodes.

Comment: @thatOneGuy, it would be great if the labels "value" in the set "links" are shown over the corresponding links.

Comment: right ok, first off you're not bringing the value through from your original data. Second, you are currently displaying bilinks which consists of, i think, three nodes in its data ? So again no value here. Can i ask, what does the data in bilinks represent?

Comment: @thatOneGuy, in the links set the format is the following: {"source":0,"target":2,"value":2}. So the idea is to show the "value" datum over the corresponding link.

Comment: I thought of bilinks as a definition for the links, i.e. edges.

Comment: yes but why does the data for an individual bi link contain 3 objects ?

Comment: I think it is to create a nonlinear edge, @thatOneGuy. The method was looked up [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4600693).

Comment: You think? Is this not your code ? I will answer the question with what I have put together, hopefully it will help

Comment: @thatOneGuy, I started coding in js two days ago, so I am not entirely sure about everything I do. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this example : http://jsfiddle.net/7HZcR/3/

I have created the same view but with your data here : http://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/7HZcR/515/

So you need to implement the arrows.

What you had previously, you couldn't log the data on `mouseover` as the data you brought through didn't contain it.

So in this one I have brought the data through like so :

```
var links = graph.links;
```

Set it to your data, but since this only has indexes as source and target you need to attach nodes to the source and target so it targets correctly :

```
// Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
links.forEach(function(link) {
  link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
  link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
});
```

Now the data brought back would be along the lines of :

```
{
   source : someNode,
   target : someNode,
   value : linkValue
}
```

So I have created a text output as to work out where to put the value on the link would be difficult as you have to work out the curve etc :

```
var textOutput = svg.append('text').attr('class', 'textOutput')
.attr("transform","translate(50, 100)");
```

So on `mouseover` set the textOutput :

```
.on('mouseover', function(d){
    console.log(d);
    d3.select(this).style('stroke', 'red').style('stroke-width', '5')
    textOutput.text('LINK VALUE : ' + d.value);
    })
     .on('mouseout', function(d){ 
    d3.select(this).style('stroke', '#666') .style('stroke-width', '1')
    });
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you very much, @thatOneGuy!

Comment: @J.Tanizaki I have updated answer again so link stroke changes so you know which link you are on :)

Comment: you are most helpful!