# How can I add text to edges in a force directed graph d3?

Tags: d3.js

I want to be able to add text along the sides of my edges between nodes. However, the way that I was able to display text on top of my nodes doesn't seem to work for adding text to the edges. How do I go about this? Is there a different approach I should be trying?

I've looked extensively into other threads regarding this issue but I can't seem to understand why my code isn't working / get theirs to work on my graph. I'm a beginner to d3 and Javascript so maybe I'm overlooking something simple.

A link to my code can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/obe02/zxva4f5r/

````
  // update existing links
  path.classed("selected", (d) => d === selectedLink)
      .style("marker-start", function(d) {return getMarkers(d, false, true)})
      .style("marker-end", function(d) {return getMarkers(d, false, false)});

  // remove old links
  path.exit().remove();

  // add new links
  path = path.enter().append("svg:path")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .classed("selected", (d) => d === selectedLink)
    .style("marker-start", function(d) {return getMarkers(d, false, true)})
    .style("marker-end", function(d) {return getMarkers(d, false, false)})
    .on("mousedown", (d) => {
      if (d3.event.shiftKey) return;

      // select link
      mousedownLink = d;
      selectedLink = (mousedownLink === selectedLink) ? null : mousedownLink;
      selectedNode = null;
      update();
    })
    .merge(path);

path.append("svg:text")
    //.attr("dx", function(d) { return d.w/10})
    //.attr("dy", -4)
    .attr("x", function(d) {return d.length / 2})
    .attr("y", function(d) {return (d.length / 2) + 2})
    .attr("class", "edgelabel")
    .text((d) => d.length);```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here for anyone interested. It wasn't as simple as I originally thought; you have to create a few different elements to get the text to show up.

[Add text/label onto links in D3 force directed graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663844/add-text-label-onto-links-in-d3-force-directed-graph)